# Python Error :UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to process some files using threading in Python.Some threads work fine with no error but some through the below exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-27484:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "script.py", line 62, in ProcessFile
    if f is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

while running my program

Here is Python function

```
def ProcessFile(fieldType,filePath,data):
    try:
        if fieldType == 'email':
            fname = 'email.txt'
        else:
            fname = 'address.txt'
        f1 = open(fname,'wb')
        for r in data[1:]:
            r[1] = randomData(fieldType)
            f1.write(r[1])
        f1.close()

        f = open(filePath,'wb')

        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)
        f.close()
        try:
            shutil.move(filePath,processedFileDirectory)
        except:
            if not os.path.exists(fileAlreadyExistDirectory):
                os.makedirs(fileAlreadyExistDirectory)
            shutil.move(filePath,fileAlreadyExistDirectory)
    finally:
        if f is not None:
            f.close()
```

Here is how i'm calling the above function through threading

```
t = Thread(target=ProcessFile,args=(fieldType,filePath,data))
        t.start()
```

Comment: Downvoted for not providing the full traceback. You should know better with a reputation of 3000. Especially because you did not indent your code properly.

Comment: Trace back would be nice, Line number can really help.

Comment: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: Obviously an error occurs in the try block before you assign 'f' for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you got an exception somewhere in your 'try' clause before you actually wrote anything to f. So not only does f not hold a value, it doesn't even exist.

Simplest fix is to add

```
f = None
```

above the try clause. But probably, you are not expecting an exception that early, so maybe you should check the data you are sending this function

Comment: I don't think it's a fix, workaround it's more accurate description for what you wrote.